# concatenate file name and time for the file Name/pattern Mule 3

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-el

I'm trying to concatenate the filename and dateTime inside the file connector as name for the output file. I get a syntax error. This because MEL expressions already appear enclosed in double quotes in configuration files, so I have to escape the double quotes with single quotes or \u0027expression\u0027 or "("expression"). How ever none of them works.

The output file should have the following pattern:
filename-2020-02-09T12:08:53Z.json

I have tried with this function, only escaping the quotes gives  an error

```
apples-#[server.dateTime.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")].json
```

The error I get is this;

```
      "changenr...
Element               : /ref-sys-api-main/processors/5/ref-sys-api/subprocessors/5 @ ref-sys-api.xml:85 (write-file-service)
Element XML           : <file:outbound-endpoint path="G:\Local" outputPattern="apples-#[server.dateTime.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")].json" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="write-file-service"></file:outbound-endpoint>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
    at org.mule.util.FileUtils.newFile(FileUtils.java:369)
    at org.mule.util.FileUtils.createFile(FileUtils.java:95)
    at org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector.getOutputStream(FileConnector.java:561)
    at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(FileMessageDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:109)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$DispatcherMessageProcessor.process(AbstractConnector.java:2735)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:48)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:131)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:221)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:214)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:213)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

********************************************************************************

INFO  2022-02-14 14:54:37,161 [[ref-sys-api-1].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Error: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=file:///C:/Local/, connector=FileConnector


********************************************************************************
 Response error: IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @aled it looks like the colons can not be escaped HH:mm:ss I tried with ` and ' and \ al of give syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in the exception is telling the reason this doesn't work:

```
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
```

The error is not related to the syntax of the expression. It is not coming from Mule but from Windows. You can not have a file name with colons (´:´) in Windows. It may be possible in other Operating Systems but it is not worth it. Just use some different character as a time separator, or none at all.